# Inserting values into an array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a function that recursively examines an XML object loaded from file. I can retrieve the node data just fine, but when I try to insert the object with user data using the `.Insert` method, I get the error:

```
Exception calling "Insert" with "2" argument(s): "Insertion index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than or equal to size. Parameter name: index"
```

If I replace the object values with simple string test values, insert works as expected. However, I'm using an object for each pass of the loop, and building up a large object to output to a file. Here is the simplified excerpt:

```
# some dummy values #
$drives = "value1","value2"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DriveObject = @()
$DriveObject.Add("$drives") | Out-Null

# some dummy users #
$FilterUser = "User1","User2"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$UserObject = @()
$UserObject.Add("$FilterUser") | Out-Null

# insert user object into drive object #
$DriveObject.Insert($DriveObject.LastIndexOf('value2'),$UserObject)

# output #
$DriveObject
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `$DriveObject.Add("$drives")`, the expression `"$drives"` *creates a new string*, so `$DriveObject` doesn't actually contain two separate values, it contains only a single string `"value1 value2"`.

Use the `AddRange()` method to add *multiple* items to the ArrayList at a time:

```
# some dummy values #
$drives = "value1","value2"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$DriveObject = @()
$DriveObject.AddRange($drives) | Out-Null

# some dummy users #
$FilterUser = "User1","User2"
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$UserObject = @()
$UserObject.AddRange($FilterUser) | Out-Null

# insert user object into drive object #
$DriveObject.Insert($DriveObject.LastIndexOf('value2'),$UserObject)

# output #
$DriveObject
```

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that the double quotes around the value cause errors, which you removed in your modification. PowerShell syntax can be awkward! Thanks again